# Jquery find string in DOM and get his element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, contain

I there way to get element from DOM objects whitch contains some string? I am trying:

```
$( "*:contains('searchedString')" ).first().text( "test" );
```

or

```
$( "*:contains('searchedString')" ).text( "test" );
```

But this returns `<html>` object so after execute whole content dissapear and show only `test` on screen.

EDIT:

- I need search in whole document therefore `*` selector...
- DOM types can be h2, div, etc..

Comment: You'll have to be more precise in your selector. `*` won't give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: But i need search in whole document...

Comment: DOM object with the string will be input types or any other tags like `<p>` or `<div>` etc?

Comment: Sadly - yes....

Comment: html or body do have that content. you should use element tag such as `p` or `span` or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting everything with `*` will always include the `<html>` tag.

To get the deepest element, you could get the last element your selector finds using jQuery `.last()` method :

```
<div><span>test</span></div>

let deepestElement = $("*:contains('test')").last();
console.log(deepestElement);
```

Here is a working JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Zenoo0/ryjtwdqb/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the result which has no child as below:

```js
var result = $( "*:contains('searchedString'):not(:has(*))" ).text( "test" );
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>searchedString</span>
</div>
```

Or You can limit the selector with tags to avoid results you don't want.

And you can use `filter` to get the useful part.

```js
var tags = ['div', 'p', 'span'];
var str = "";
var result = $(tags.join(',')).filter(':contains("searchedString")');
console.log(result.length);
// ... filter result or something
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>searchedString</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "h1,h2,div:contains(searchStrinng)" ).first().text( "test" );
$( "h1,h2,div:contains(searchStrinng)" ).text( "test" );

Example:
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2>Hello</h2>

- For first element (include only h1,h2,div) 
$( "h1,h2,div:contains(Hello)" ).first().text( "test" );

- For all element(include only h1,h2,div)
$( "h1,h2,div:contains(Hello)" ).text( "test" );
```